# How to parse XML using angular js?

Tags: xml, angularjs, cordova, xml-parsing

I want to parse XML using URL:http://callme.myshareus.nl/API/getGroups.php?APIkey=te7gRRT8Ut2VYW&InitiatorId=0000001&JobId=00000260&Role=1
 in angular js.

and output of XML is:

```
<Groups>
<entity no="1">
<SU val="GROUPID">000001</SU>
<SU val="GROUPNAME">Rick Brusse group</SU>
</entity>
<entity no="2">
<SU val="GROUPID">000027</SU>
<SU val="GROUPNAME">MV Aseguradores group</SU>
</entity>
<entity no="3">
<SU val="GROUPID">000095</SU>
<SU val="GROUPNAME">test group 20-1-2012</SU>
</entity>
<entity no="4">
<SU val="GROUPID">000096</SU>
<SU val="GROUPNAME">test 1</SU>
</entity>
<entity no="5">
<SU val="GROUPID">000106</SU>
<SU val="GROUPNAME">test 2</SU>
</entity>
</Groups>
```

I am trying

```
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,xx,x,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("SU");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + "<tr>";
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("GROUPID");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
          }
        }
    xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("GROUPNAME");
      {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
          }
        }
      txt=txt + "</tr>";
      }
    txt=txt + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And I am passing the url on clling of function,

```
loadXMLDoc('http://callme.myshareus.nl/API/getGroups.phpAPIkey=te7gRRT8Ut2VYW&InitiatorId=0000001&JobId=00000260&Role=1');
```

Not woking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse XML in javascript in both IE and firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272538/how-can-i-parse-xml-in-javascript-in-both-ie-and-firefox)

Comment: @harshuli You can use some xml parser like [fast-xml-parser](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/fast-xml-parser/), xml2js etc. Once they are parsed to regular js object, use them as per your need.